# Float:Left and Position not working for email campaign

Tags: html, css, css-float, mailchimp

I have all of the code posted below for my email campaign. For some reason the "float" attribute doesn't work in Gmail and Yahoo so I'm wondering if there is a way around using "float" so that it will appear nicely formatted in an email. Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f3f4f5; margin:0px;">
    <div style="width:600px; margin:0px auto;">
        <div style="width:100%; float:left; box-shadow: 0 0 12px #CCCCCC;margin-top: 70px;">
            <div style="width:94%; float:left;padding:32px 3%;background-color:#0078ae;">
                <a href="http://realscout.com"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/logo.png" style="max-width:100%;">
            </a></div>
            <div style="width:94%; height: 50%; float:left;padding:0px 3%;
            position:relative;
            background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f4f4f4 50%, #ebebeb 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f4f4f4), color-stop(100%,#ebebeb)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f4f4f4 50%,#ebebeb 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f4f4f4 50%,#ebebeb 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f4f4f4 50%,#ebebeb 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f4f4f4 50%,#ebebeb 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ebebeb',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
">
                <h1 style="color: #0078AD;font-family: verdana;font-size: 28px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 28px;margin: 0;padding: 24px 0 12px;">A Real Success Story!</h1>
                <p style="color: #7F8182;font-family: verdana;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 45%;">"We LOVE RealScout! Through its simplistic approach of capturing clients to its personalized search criteria, we have been able to connect with lead generated clients better and faster than any other service we have ever used in the past. Within one month we have turned two leads into actual clients in escrow and have about 15 clients using the website on a weekly basis...this is a no brainer, go with RealScout!"</p>
                <a href="http://pro.realscout.com" style="background-color: #56B900;border: medium none;border-radius: 5px;color: #FEFFFF;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 18px;margin: 20px 0 35px;padding: 17px 15px;text-decoration: none;">Your Success Begins Here!</a>
                <img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2jahngh.jpg" style="margin-top: -306px; margin-left: 15px;">
                <span style=" background-color:#ffffff;color: #0078ad; font-family: verdana; font-size: 14px; position: relative; right:-70px; opacity: 0.8;padding: 3px 3px; text-transform: capitalize;">Heidi and Michael Syltebo
            </span></div>

            <div style="width:94%; float:left;padding:30px 3% 30px;position:relative;background-color:#f8f8f9;">
                <img src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/rjaq100u38u699nf8ckn583c14_home.png" style="max-width:48%;float: left;margin:0px 4% 0px 0px;">
                <h1 style="color: #0078AE;float:left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 22px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0 0 8px 0;width: 48%;">Social Media Tip</h1>
                <p style="color: #7F8182;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 14px;line-height: 22px; margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 48%;">Generate more leads and increase the traffic to your RealScout search portal by posting your personal links on Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter, etc. and inviting your audience to search with you on RealScout.</p>
                <a href="http://" style="background-color: #06AEEC;border: medium none;border-radius: 5px;color: #FEFFFF;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 18px;margin: 12px 0 0;padding: 20px 25px;text-decoration: none;">Get Your Links</a>
            </div>


                <div style="width:94%; float:left;padding:30px 3% 30px;position:relative;background-color:#f8f8f9;">
                <img src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/rjaq100u38u699nf8ckn583c14_website-manager.png" style="max-width:48%;float: left;margin:0px 4% 0px 0px;">
                <h1 style="color: #0078AE;float:left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 22px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0 0 8px 0;width: 48%;">New Feature Upgrade!</h1>
                <p style="color: #7F8182;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 14px;line-height: 22px; margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 48%;">Now you can manage your RealScout Website right on RealScout Pro by clicking "Manage My RealScout Website" on your Agent Dashbord.</p>
                <a href="http://www.buzzfeed.com/ryanhatesthis/this-guy-spent-the-last-month-dressing-up-like-local-realtor" style="background-color: #06AEEC;border: medium none;border-radius: 5px;color: #FEFFFF;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 18px;margin: 12px 0 0;padding: 20px 25px;text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Read More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            </div>



<div style="width:94%; float:left;padding:30px 3% 30px;position:relative;background-color:#f8f8f9;">
                <img src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/rjaq100u38u699nf8ckn583c14_enhanced-buzz-21288-1387234916-3.jpg" style="max-width:48%;float: left;margin:0px 4% 0px 0px;">
                <h1 style="color: #0078AE;float:left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 22px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0 0 8px 0;width: 48%;">Real Comedy</h1>
                <p style="color: #7F8182;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 14px;line-height: 22px; margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 48%;">Artist and designer Phil Jones spent the last month dressing up as local real estate agents and pasting himself over their bench ads.</p>
                <a href="http://www.buzzfeed.com/ryanhatesthis/this-guy-spent-the-last-month-dressing-up-like-local-realtor" style="background-color: #06AEEC;border: medium none;border-radius: 5px;color: #FEFFFF;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 18px;margin: 12px 0 0;padding: 20px 25px;text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Laugh More&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            </div>



            <div style="width:100%;float:left;position:relative; margin-top: 0px;">
                <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-estate-by-realscout-search/id744305884?mt=8"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/new.png" style="margin:-6px 0px 0px -6px;">
                </a><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-estate-by-realscout-search/id744305884?mt=8"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/slider.jpg" style="float: left;margin-top: -119px;width: 100%;">
                <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF;bottom: 45px;float: right;margin: -140px 0 0;padding: 15px 25px;width: 41%;">
                <h1 style="color: #06AEEC;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0 0 10px;text-transform: capitalize;width: 100%;">Save Searches Across Devices</h1>
                    <p style="color: #7F8182;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 13px;line-height: 23px; margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;">RealScout is compatible with all your 
desktop and mobile devices.</p>
                </div>
            </a></div>

            <ul style="background-color: #FFFFFF;float: left;margin: 0;padding: 40px 0 0;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
                <li style="float: left;list-style: none outside none; padding: 0 1% 40px;width: 31%;">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/border_bg.png" style="float: right;margin: 0 -7px 0 0;">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/icon1.png" style="height: 49px;">
                    <h1 style="color: #484848;font-family: verdana;font-weight: normal;margin:10px 0;font-size: 18px;">30 Days Free</h1>
                    <p style="color: #BCBCBC;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;margin:0px 0px 10px;">Refer 2 Realtors and get an extra 30 days free!*</p>
                    <a href="mailto:sales@realscout.com" style="color: #0881B4;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;text-decoration: none;margin:10px 0px;">Referring is easy - Try it now!</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float: left;list-style: none outside none; padding: 0 1% 40px;width: 31%;">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/border_bg.png" style="float: right;margin: 0 -7px 0 0;">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/icon2.png" style="height: 49px;">
                    <h1 style="color: #484848;font-family: verdana;font-weight: normal;margin:10px 0;font-size: 18px;">Contact Us</h1>
                    <p style="color: #BCBCBC;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;margin:0px 0px 10px;">We're here to help answer your questions.</p>
                    <a href="mailto:support@realscout.com" style="color: #0881B4;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;text-decoration: none;margin:10px 0px;">Reply or Call (650) 397-6500</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float: left;list-style: none outside none; padding: 0 1% 40px;width: 31%;">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0b32d9562fc9af3777504e182/images/icon3.png" style="height: 49px;">
                    <h1 style="color: #484848;font-family: verdana;font-weight: normal;margin:10px 0;font-size: 18px;">FAQ</h1>
                    <p style="color: #BCBCBC;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;margin:0px 0px 10px;">Have other questions?</p>
                    <span href="support.realscout.com" style="color: #0881B4;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;margin:10px 0px;"><a href="http://support.realscout.com" style="color: #0881B4;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;text-decoration: none;margin:10px 0px;">Visit our support center for FAQ's and video tutorials.</a></span>
                </li>


        </ul></div>
        <p style="color: #0078AD;float: left;font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;margin: 50px 0 15px;text-align: center;width: 100%;">*Recieve an extra 30 days FREE when you refer 2 Realtors who sign up on RealScout!</p>
        <span style="color: #A2A2A3;float: left;font-family: arial;margin: 0 0 35px;text-align: center;width: 100%;font-size: 14px;">Copyright ©2014 RealScout. All Rights Reserved. <a href="#" style="color: #A2A2A3;">Unsubscribe</a></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome back in the hell of HTML table layouts... Campaign Monitor extensive tests should be handy: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ And Mailchimp recommended by the #1 answer here, too.

Answer (score 0):

The way around floats is to turn to tables.

If you would like some examples you can check out [Mailchimp's Templates](http://mailchimp.com/features/email-templates/)

They even have some cool responsive templates.

This may also help you understand email support for css... http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

** Note: I don't mean to promote Mailchimp as I am not affiliated, but they do have some good references when it comes to email

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients still strip out floats, negative margins, and any CSS that is included in a head tag. Some also add their own CSS that can replace all or part of yours. The best you can do is to plan ahead to design emails that can gracefully degrade in browsers that don't support or don't fully support CSS, and test, test, test. Alternatively, there are some good email templates out there. Mailchimp is - as noted by others - a great resource.

For floats, before you try tables, try adding "text-align: left;" to the parent element. This may get your alignment close to correct.

If you have to move to tables, you can add classes to the cells, and in the head set the td's to display as inline-blocks with floats.

(As an aside, a jsFiddle would help to allow others to see how your code is behaving and tweak it. It helps make it easier to give a precise answer.)